# Find the coordinates of the point $P$ on the graph of $f(x) = 9-x^2$ at which the tangent line passes through $(4, 0)$.

Tags: calculus

Find the coordinates of the point $P$ on the graph of $f(x) = 9-x^2$ at which the tangent line passes through $(4, 0)$. This is what I have done so far. $(a,(9-a^2))$ <- this is the point at $P$ where the tangent line will lie. $f'(a) = -2a$. Then I plug in the points $(4,0)$ into the point slope formula. I get $0-(9-a^2) = -2a(4-a)$. This equals $a^2-8a+9=0$. However, I cannot get a clean factor out of this equation. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a^2 - 8a + 9 = 0$$ is a quadratic equation. Therefore, it can be solved by the quadratic formula:

$$a =  4 \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{38} $$

Comment: good catch thanks. Plugged it into my quadratic program on calculator and it works.